# How to create a shared drive with Google Drive API (node.js)

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to make a script that makes a shared drive from the google drive api but right now I'm getting an error inside the createSharedDrive(auth) function where it says

```
drive.drives.create
```

as it's saying the 'create' function is undefined. Not sure how to fix it. The google drive api documentation doesn't show the entire script to create a shared drive.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const { uuid } = require('uuidv4');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Drive API.
  //authorize(JSON.parse(content), listFiles);
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), createSharedDrive);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

function createSharedDrive(auth){
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
  var driveMetadata = {
  'name': 'Testing Create Shared Drive'
  };
  var requestId = uuid;
  drive.drives.create({
    resource: driveMetadata,
    requestId: requestId,
    fields: 'id'
  }, function (err, drive) {
    if (err) {
      // Handle error
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Drive Id: ', drive.id);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The create method does not contains any "resource" property. It contains a `requestId` property and a `requestBody` property; Therefore, your request should look like this:

```
function createSharedDrive(auth){
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
  var driveMetadata = {
      'name': 'Testing Create Shared Drive'
  };
  var requestId = uuid;
  drive.drives.create({
    requestBody: driveMetadata,
    requestId: requestId,
    fields: 'id'
  }, function (err, drive) {
    if (err) {
      // Handle error
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Drive Id: ', drive.id);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined"

Comment: on the documentation it has "driveService.drives.create" but i dont see what type driveService is (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-shareddrives)